# What is the semantics of the html element?

Tags: css, html, dom, domdocument

Recently I've dived deeper into web technologies and the good old **HTML**.

I was surpised by the central role of the `html` element in **rendering** (e.g. it has a `width` and a `height`) hence a **visual semantics**.

I thought `html` was only the root of the **HTML document**, which allows to pack together **metadata** in the `head` element and visual data in the `body` element which itself has a clear visual semantics.

It raises some questions about the exact nature of the `html` element:

- conceptually what exactly does it represent?
- where is its semantics defined?
- apart from its size (`width` and `height`) and `background`, how does it affect visual rendering?
- can we say that its parent is the **viewport**?

Comment: The semantics of the html element are that it is the root of an HTML document. Simple as that. Its rendering is a matter of CSS and has no bearing on its meaning in HTML whatsoever. Not sure where you pulled the term "visual semantics" from.

Comment: A google search for "visual semantics" yields 7.87 million hits, so while I had never heard the term, it obviously exists.

Comment: And which of those 7.87 million hits did the asker pull it from?

Comment: I pulled this term out of my head. ;) I've explained what I mean in the comment to *Quentin*'s answer. And yes it's more of a CSS "issue" than pure HTML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> visual semantics

Semantics and presentation are different things. Semantics describe meaning. Presentation describes appearance. The presentation should convey the meaning to the viewer. (And CSS describes how to translate the semantics into the visual cues that do that).

> conceptually what exactly does the html element represent?

An HTML document.

> where is its semantics defined?

In [the HTML recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/semantics.html#the-html-element).

> apart from its size (width and height) and background, how does it affect visual rendering?

That depends on what CSS is applied to it.

> can we say that the parent of the htmlelement is the viewport?

No. It is the document object.

```js
console.log(document.querySelector("html").parentNode === document);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer *Quentin*. By "visual semantics" I mean what it represents visually (in the end for the user) like a `div` is a box, the `body` is the main display area, an `img` is an image... But indeed it has probably more to do with **CSS** than **HTML**.

Comment: So the question is more: how CSS defines what the `html` element represents?

Comment: @Pragmateek - in that sense, `html`,  `div` and `body` may all, depending on the CSS assigned to it, be zero, one or more boxes. It's not really helpful.

Comment: @Alohci Indeed in CSS almost all is a box but with different purposes.